# How to wait for desired input in InputDialog?

Tags: java, swing

I want to call a new `JFrame` if and only if the input from the `InputDialog is not empty string i.e. I want to wait for the user to enter something before he hits ok. How can I do that?

Comment: so you can disable button! validate textfield using Listener. like don't enable button until the textfield not empty. Simple..!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must check result and to inform user about some input.

```
String myInputString = myJTextField.getText();
if (!myInputString.isEmpty()) {
    myJOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, "Please, input somesing.");
}
```

May be [this will useful](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup) for you.

Comment: +1 for the JOptionPane and the link to the Swing tutorial that provides working code.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...... .......**

```
public class a{  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Customer ID", "Input",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,null,"");
            if(selectedValue !=null){
            ///Call your frame

            }
        }
}
```